# PHP: Pass variable to function

Tags: php, arrays, function, laravel-5, parameter-passing

Looks simple (and maybe) but I need pass a received variable in a function to another function. Here's my code:

PD: I using Laravel Eloquent's Scopes

```
class myParentModel extends Model {

    public function scopeMyScope($query, $VAR_I_WANT_TO_PASS=[]) {

        return $query->with('model'])->whereHas('model', function($q, $VAR_I_WANT_TO_PASS=[]) {

            $q->where('colum1',$VAR_I_WANT_TO_PASS[0])->where('colum2',$VAR_I_WANT_TO_PASS[1])->where('colum3',$VAR_I_WANT_TO_PASS[2]);

        })->take(10);

    }
}
```

and I want to do this:

```
$result = myParentModel::myScope([3,1,6])->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolve this using `use`:

```
class myParentModel extends Model {

    public function scopeMyScope($query, $VAR_I_WANT_TO_PASS) {

        return $query->with('model'])->whereHas('model', function($q) use ($VAR_I_WANT_TO_PASS) {

            $q->where('colum1',$VAR_I_WANT_TO_PASS[0])->where('colum2',$VAR_I_WANT_TO_PASS[1])->where('colum3',$VAR_I_WANT_TO_PASS[2]);

        })->take(10);

    }
}
```